basename complains about missing operand using unshare
If I try to create namespaces, basename complains about missing operand:
sudo unshare --mount --ipc --uts --pid --fork --user  /bin/bash
basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information.

I even tried with bash --norc with no luck.
Why does this error occur? And how do I fix it?
UPDATE 1
When I said that "I even tried with bash --norc with no luck."  I meant that I run bash --norc and then sudo unshare....
but that it works:
sudo unshare --mount --ipc --uts --pid --fork --user /bin/bash --norc --noprofile

I wonder anyway why. Because I have basename in .bashrc only into functions, and disabling those functions it outputs the same error

Try sudo unshare --mount --ipc --uts --pid --fork --user env PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO} ' /bin/bash -x to see where the complaint comes from

Comment from @muru was really helpful.
The basename error is because of:
  /etc/bashrc:78 . /etc/profile.d/which2.sh
   /etc/profile.d/which2.sh:4 case "$(basename $(readlink /proc/$$/exe))" in
     /etc/profile.d/which2.sh:4 readlink /proc/1/exe
    /etc/profile.d/which2.sh:4 basename
basename: falta un operando
Pruebe 'basename --help' para más información.

In short: there is no permission to access to /proc/1/exe in the new namespaces.
